# Wrong "if" logic PHP

Tags: php, sql

I think I didn't understand the PHP logic yet. My "if's" in javascript works fine, but in PHP it's always ignored. I have this form (party of it) in insert_car.php:

```
<input type="file" name="imagem01" id="imagem01" title="Imagem 01" onchange="readURL01(this);" class="button" />
```

... (and 5 more inputs for images and others for texts)

this is the correspondent party in insert_db.php:

```
$gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];

preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem01["name"], $ext);

$nome_imagem01 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
$caminho_imagem01 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem01;

move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem01["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem01);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_carros (... imagem01,...) value (... '$nome_imagem01',...)";
```

It works fine, but know I want to put an default image if one of the inputs file is empty. So I did this in insert_db.php:

```
if (empty($imagem01))
{
    $gravar_imagem01 = "sem_imagem.jpg";
    $nome_imagem01 = $gravar_imagem01;
}
else
{
    $gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];

    preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem01["name"], $ext);

    $nome_imagem01 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
    $caminho_imagem01 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem01;

    move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem01["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem01);
}
```

The default image (sem_imagem.jpg) is been placed, but even if the input "imagem01" is not empty the default image appears. So, what is wrong in my code?

Ps.: If I switch the "if" and "else" condition the result is the reverse (the default image don't appears even with the input imagem01 empty). That's why I said that my "if" is been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` isn't being "ignored"; you likely misunderstood the meaning of the function [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Look it up in the documentation, and check that it does what you think it does.

In particular, it doesn't magically understand the concept of "files" — `empty` looks at *variables*. It is quite conceivable that `$_FILES['imagem01']` still exists in some form even in the case in which you're perceiving the image file to be "empty". I suggest examining it in this case to find out which conditional to use.

---

**Edit:** It also helps if you use the correct variable name:

```
if (empty($imagem01))
```

becomes:

```
if (empty($_FILES['imagem01']))
```

Comment: It works too but with the same error of Mohammad answer. I don't know why but when the input is empty, the insert_db.php still generate an md5 uniq name (but without the extention .jpg).

Comment: @AdrianoMachado: I don't follow you. You need to narrow down your problem(s) further. Do some debugging!

Comment: I said to Mohammad (two answers down) that it works when I select a image to input file, but if I don't select a image it show's an broken image icon instead of the 'sem_imagem.jpg'. With your code that happened too. And when I open the source page on the browser or the table on phpMyAdmin there is an image (value) with md5 uniq name without the `jpg` extention. But into the `if (empty($_FILES['imagem01']))` I didn't put the md5 code to do that. In this case (empty input) I just want to save `sem_imagem.jpg` as `imagem01` value on the table.

Comment: @AdrianoMachado: tl;dr you haven't performed any debugging. I'm not going to take you iteratively through every step of programming your webpage and every error that you come across. It's also very difficult to tell what you're talking about.

Comment: I understand... thanks a lot... I'll take a look in the documentation to understand how it really works.

Comment: Lightness, just one more question that I think I can't find the answer in the documentation ... The validation of the empty input is in the right document (insert_db.php)? Or should I do this in the insert_car.php (before send the form)?

Answer (score 1):

try this i think always `$imagem01`   is empty you must get `imagem01` data from form like `$imagem01= $_FILES['imagem01'];` then check for empty `you can't use JavaScript variable directly` it better in this case use `var_dump($var);` for see variable value

```
 $imagem01= $_FILES['imagem01'];
 if (empty($imagem01))
 {
   $gravar_imagem01 = "sem_imagem.jpg";
   $nome_imagem01 = $gravar_imagem01;
 }
  else
  {
    $gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];
    preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $gravar_imagem01["name"], $ext);
    $nome_imagem01 = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];
    $caminho_imagem01 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem01;
    move_uploaded_file($gravar_imagem01["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem01);
 }
```

Comment: I got the same results Mohammad. If I change the 'if (!empty($imagem01))' to 'if (empty($imagem01))', it works when I select a image to input file, but if I don't select a image it show's an broken image icon instead of the 'sem_imagem.jpg'.

Comment: yes you right it must be `if (empty($imagem01))` where you echo image for show. maybe your code want show  `sem_imagem.jpg` from  this address `$caminho_imagem01 = "../../images/" . $nome_imagem01;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `isset`

change this

```
if (empty($imagem01))
```

to

```
$gravar_imagem01 = $_FILES['imagem01'];
if (isset($gravar_imagem01))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable named `$imagem01` anywhere else in your code so it is always going to be undefined and `empty($imagem01)` will always return true. You may need to check for a different condition in your `if` statement.